# Were the Egyptian Four Horsemen characters from the comics?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, x-men-apocalypse, marvel

In the opening sequence of X-Men: Apocalypse, we see the "Four Horsemen" of Apocalypse

> during his life transfer ritual.

These are not the original Four Horsemen of Apocalypse from the comics: War, Famine, Pestilence, & Death. However, are the characters shown in the film other mutants from the comics, or original characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the IMDB [page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3385516/) for the film, they are given exaclty these names, War, Famine, Pestilence, Death. This choice though might have been made only for nominal/practical purposes as they are not named in any part of it.

> The one who dies last, surviving long enough to protect Apocalypse's body is named as Death and seems to control various powers, including telepathy, telekinisis, force field creation..

Comment: Apocalypse typically uses those names for whichever four mutants are his Horsemen. For example, when Angel is turned into Archangel in the comics, Apocalypse calls him "Death". This may be all the info there is to find, though.

Comment: @Discord I fear as much myself. Also I find it a pitty they did not expand on them more..They appeared far more capable and devoted than his "new" acolytes.